# Query not executing after exiting method

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, uwp

I have a simple insert query running from a web service I have written. On button click I have it running a method that calls the web service and executes the insert query. For some reason it does not actually insert the information until I have exited the on click event... Can anyone tell me why? I will post code below:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //inserts new article into DB
        Insert();
    }

 private void InsertNewArticle()
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client service = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

        ArticleDetails articleInfo = new ArticleDetails();
        articleInfo.Title = newsTitle;
        articleInfo.Body = newsBody;
        articleInfo.Author = newsAuthor;

        service.InsertArticleDetailsAsync(articleInfo);
    }
```

What I have seen through debugging it, is that it does not execute until it exits the `btnSubmit_Click` event. The reason this is a problem for me is I am wanting to do something with the information that was just submitted before exiting the on click event.

Note: This is a **Universal Windows Application**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling an asynchronous method but doesn't wait for it to execute. Change the InsertNewArticle method to

```
private async void InsertNewArticle()
{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client service = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    ArticleDetails articleInfo = new ArticleDetails();
    articleInfo.Title = newsTitle;
    articleInfo.Body = newsBody;
    articleInfo.Author = newsAuthor;

    await service.InsertArticleDetailsAsync(articleInfo);
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks a lot for your answer. Will mark it answered when it allows me to